# Find Two numbers When added to give Target number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I wrote this code to find two numbers when added give a target number.
I have already solved this exercise but I want to make with this way above
in the if statement didn't return true and I  don't know why.

```
function add(arr , target){
    let result = [];
    arr.map ( (item) => {
        const num1 = target - item;
        if (arr.includes(num1)) {
            return result.concat(num1 , item);
        }
        else {
            return "Unfortunaly there isnt answer";
        }
    });
}

add([3,4,5,6,10] , 16);
```

Comment: You want to find any two numbers in the array which when added give target number? Am I right?

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: you rigth N Djokic... @N.Djokic

Comment: and should return [10 , 6]  @User863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function add(arr , target){
    let result = [];
    for (let item of arr){
        const num1 = target - item;
        if (arr.includes(num1)) {
            return result.concat(num1 , item);
        }
    };
    return "Unfortunately there is no answer";
}

const result = add([3,4,5,6,10] , 16);

// will print [10, 6]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You have the right answer (the questioner is mis-using the map method and you have correctly changed this to a for loop), however I think you also need some explanation.

Comment: @EuanSmith yes it is... but why did you use for of loops... all of other are same

Comment: `map` and `for` are _NOT_ the same.  I suggest checking out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).  My point above was to Ricardo as he has supplied your answer he should try and provide some explanation.

Comment: @EuanSmith you are right I should have provided more info. Hope the mdn docs have enough information to clarify Onur Hangul, if not tell me and I will provide some explanations with code examples.